# Flask read csv file with pandas - File Not Found Error

Tags: python, pandas, flask

I am trying to load a CSV into a pandas dataframe and I'm getting a "No such file or directory" error.

My project structure is like this:

[image]

The function that loads the data from the csv is as such:

```
def generate_1():
    # Read data from CSVs
    current_df = pd.read_csv(url_for('static', filename='data/test.csv'))
```

The error says:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/static/data/test.csv'
```

And yet we can see the file is on that path in the project directory.

Any ideas what is happening? Thank you.

Comment: Note that the pathname reportedly not found is absolute. That is not where your file is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because the application tries to search the CSV file in the root directory of the host machine. To solve it, you might want to consider using relative paths.

```sh
./static/data/test.csv # if the file in a static folder inside the execution context
../static/data/test.csv # if the file is in the parent directory
../../static/data/test.csv # if the file is in the grandparent directory
```

In your case, you'd be interested with:

```sh
./static/data/test.csv
```

or use `os.path.relpath`:

```py
>>> from os.path import relpath
>>> relpath('./static/data/test.csv')
```

Comment: If the current working directory is *app* then static/data/test.csv would suffice

Comment: @JCaesar Agree man!